# Inject multiple stores to scenes with Asp.net Boilerplate

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, mobx, aspnetboilerplate, mobx-react

Which is the correct way of injecting multiple stores into a scene? I couldn't find any example about this. Everyone injects just one store into a scene. Is there a rule or concept in Asp.net boilerplate about using stores with mobx-react?

**İnjecting to component**

```js
import RefineryStore from '../../stores/refineryStore';
import Stores from '../../stores/storeIdentifier';
import UserStore from '../../stores/userStore';

export interface IRefineryProps {
    refineryStore: RefineryStore;
    userStore: UserStore;
}

@inject(Stores.RefineryStore, Stores.UserStore) // Why noone adds two stores into one inject?
@observer
class Refineries extends AppComponentBase<IRefineryProps, IRefineryState> {
   public render() {
        const { refineries } = this.props.refineryStore;
        const { managers } = this.props.userStore;
        return ()
  }
}
```

**Defining Stores class**

```js
export default class Stores {
  static AuthenticationStore: string = 'authenticationStore';
  static RoleStore: string = 'roleStore';
  static TenantStore: string = 'tenantStore';
  static UserStore: string = 'userStore';
  static SessionStore: string = 'sessionStore';
  static AccountStore: string = 'accountStore';
  static RefineryStore: string = 'refineryStore';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is totally fine to inject several stores if you need them. You can even have `RootStore` which combines everything and inject every store in every component, for example.

The modern approach would be to use hooks as described in [this docs](https://mobx-react.js.org/recipes-migration)

With that way your components would look much simpler:

```js
const Refineries = observer(() => {
  const { refineryStore, userStore } = useStores()

  return (
    <div>
      ...
    </div>
  )
})
```

Although it would require you to use functional components instead of class, so you still might want to stick to `inject` if you have big legacy app and not much time for refactoring.